Connecting Arduino to Android Studio
Is it possible to connect Arduino project in android studio? I have here the Arduino Uno 3 and my GP2Y1014AU0F Compact Optical Dust Sensor. Im having a problem, I think the implementation ("com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.7.3") is not working? Because there's an error in my Fragment, the error is

Could not find com.hoho.android:usb-serial-for-android:3.3.0.

even though its in the implementation already.
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialDriver;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialPort;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialProber;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CurrentFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    UsbManager usbManager;
    UsbDevice device;
    UsbSerialPort port;
    SpeedView speedView;
    TextView textView;

    public CurrentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static CurrentFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CurrentFragment fragment = new CurrentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("param1", param1);
        args.putString("param2", param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            // Get parameters if needed
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current, container, false);

        speedView = view.findViewById(R.id.speedView);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Button acuteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.acute);
        Button goodButton = view.findViewById(R.id.good);
        Button unhealthButton = view.findViewById(R.id.unhealthy);
        Button emergencyButton = view.findViewById(R.id.emergency);
        Button veryunhealthyButton = view.findViewById(R.id.veryunhealthy);
        Button fairButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fair);

        acuteButton.setAlpha(0f);
        goodButton.setAlpha(0f);
        unhealthButton.setAlpha(0f);
        emergencyButton.setAlpha(0f);
        veryunhealthyButton.setAlpha(0f);
        fairButton.setAlpha(0f);

        acuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFragment(new AcuteFragment());
            }
        });

        goodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFragment(new GoodFragment());
            }
        });

        unhealthButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFragment(new UnhealthyFragment());
            }
        });

        emergencyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFragment(new CurrentFragment());
            }
        });

        veryunhealthyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFragment(new VeryUnhealthyFragment());
            }
        });

        fairButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFragment(new FairFragment());
            }
        });

        usbManager = (UsbManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);

        for (UsbDevice device : usbManager.getDeviceList().values()) {
            usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                            UsbSerialDriver driver = UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().probeDevice(device);
                            if (driver != null) {
                                port = driver.getPorts().get(0);
                                try {
                                    port.open(connection);
                                    port.setParameters(9600, 8, UsbSerialPort.STOPBITS_1, UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                                    Log.d("USB", "Port opened and configured");

                                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            while (true) {
                                                try {
                                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
                                                    int numBytesRead = port.read(buffer, 1000);
                                                    final String data = new String(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
                                                    Log.d("USB", "Data read: " + data);
                                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run() {
                                                            updateUI(data);
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                                    Log.e("USB", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }).start();

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.e("USB", "Port open failed: " + e.getMessage());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.e("USB", "Driver is null");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void updateUI(String data) {
        try {
            float dustDensity = Float.parseFloat(data.trim().split(" ")[2]);
            speedView.speedTo(dustDensity);
            textView.setText("Dust Density: " + dustDensity + " ug/m3");

            if (dustDensity <= 25) {
                speedView.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.good));
            } else if (dustDensity <= 35) {
                speedView.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fair));
            } else if (dustDensity <= 45) {
                speedView.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.unhealthy));
            } else if (dustDensity <= 55) {
                speedView.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.very_unhealthy));
            } else if (dustDensity <= 90) {
                speedView.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.acute_unhealthy));
            } else {
                speedView.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.emergency));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(usbReceiver);
    }

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout1, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}


Android Studio is the development IDE used to develop Java/Kotlin/NDK apps for Android. there is no way to use it to build something for Arduino. But I assume your question is simply formulated in a wrong way and you wanted to ask if it is possible to establish a communication between an Arduino and an Android app e.g. via USB then this should be possible see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/23042753/150978

Hi sir, my only problem and error is about 'Could not find com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.7.3.
Required by:
project :app'
Im kinda new for this, "connecting arduinos to android studio"

Have you read the documentation how to use it? https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android?tab=readme-ov-file#quick-start

I already programmed the Arduino board sir, in Arduino IDE. All I need now is design the app in Android Studio, it is for my Capstone Project
